# VBA not showing any result on worksheet

Tags: vba

Why there are no results in the worksheet when I run my code. Is there something wrong with my code. Could someone please verify. This is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Globalstrahlung, Koll_ein_o, Koll_aus_o, Aussentemp, MIDsolar As Double
Dim a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2, e1, e2, f1, f2, g1, g2, x As Double
Dim cpTyf, RohTyf As Double
Dim Psolar, Puse_coll, Coll_eff As Double
Dim iCntr As Long

For iCntr = 3 To 8640

    Globalstrahlung = Range("B" & iCntr)
    Koll_ein_o = Range("C" & iCntr)
    Koll_aus_o = Range("D" & iCntr)
    Aussentemp = Range("E" & iCntr)
    MIDsolar = Range("F" & iCntr)

    x = (Koll_ein_o + Koll_aus_o) / 2

    x = Range("AW" & iCntr)

    'Function cp(t) Tyfocor 35%
    a1 = 3.5199
    b1 = 0.0042
    c1 = -0.00002
    d1 = 0.0000009
    e1 = -0.00000002
    f1 = 0.0000000001
    g1 = -0.0000000000005

    cpTyf = a1 + (b1 * x) + (c1 * (x ^ 2)) + (d1 * (x ^ 3)) + (e1 * (x ^ 4)) + (f1 * (x ^ 5)) + (g1 * (x ^ 6))

    cpTyf = Range("AX" & iCntr)

    'Function Roh(t) Tyfocor 35%
    a2 = 1045
    b2 = -0.453
    c2 = 0.0051
    d2 = 0.00007
    e2 = -0.0000007
    f2 = 0.000000004
    g2 = -0.00000000001

    RohTyf = a2 + (b2 * x) + (c2 * (x ^ 2)) + (d2 * (x ^ 3)) + (e2 * (x ^ 4)) + (f2 * (x ^ 5)) + (g2 * (x ^ 6))

    RohTyf = Range("AY" & iCntr)

    'Collector capacity

    Puse_coll = (MIDsolar / 3600) * cpTyf * RohTyf * (Koll_aus_o - Koll_ein_o)

    Puse_coll = Range("AZ" & iCntr)

    'Solar capacity
    Psolar = Globalstrahlung * 18.12

    Psolar = Range("BA" & iCntr)

    'Collector efficiency
    If Globalstrahlung = 0 Then
    Coll_eff = 0

    ElseIf Globalstrahlung <> 0 Then
    Coll_eff = (Puse_coll) / (Psolar)

    End If

Coll_eff = Range("BB" & iCntr)

Range("BB" & iCntr).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

Range("BB" & iCntr).NumberFormat = "0.00"


Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like this:

`Dim a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2, e1, e2, f1, f2, g1, g2, x As Double`

only `x` is declared as a Double data type, everything else is declared as Variant.

Second point, something like

`cpTyf = Range("AX" & iCntr)`

where cpTyf is a Variant can result in unexpected results because you haven't explicitly stated that you want to access the `.Value` property of the range object.

But in answer to your question, I'm going to assume that you're operating your statements the wrong way around (unless you want to assign a value, and then assign a completely different value immediately afterwards?).

Instead of:

```
Puse_coll = (MIDsolar / 3600) * cpTyf * RohTyf * (Koll_aus_o - Koll_ein_o)

Puse_coll = Range("AZ" & iCntr)
```

Use

```
Puse_coll = (MIDsolar / 3600) * cpTyf * RohTyf * (Koll_aus_o - Koll_ein_o)

Range("AZ" & iCntr).Value = Puse_coll
```

Comment: It works after I put .Value. Thank you very much. You said that, if I do this:Dim a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2, e1, e2, f1, f2, g1, g2, x As Double.Only x will be declared as Double. If I want a1 and the others to be Double as well, should I do like this: Dim a1 as Double, (next sentence) Dim a2 as Double

Comment: Yes, you don't need to use separate sentences though, the following will work:

`Dim a As Double, b As Double, c As Double` etc... as long as there is a declaration after each variable name and you have used the `Dim` keyword at the start of the line.

Comment: I know that declaring unnecessary value as Variant can lead to time and memory consuming.Thank you for your tips.

Answer (score 1):

Try qualifying the `Range` method with a specific sheet, e.g.,

```
Sheet1.Range("BB" & iCntr).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

or

```
Sheets("name-of-sheet").Range("BB" & iCntr).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

You can save yourself some typing by using a With statement, like this:

```
With Sheets("My Sheet")

    ' more code

    .Range("BB" & iCntr).NumberFormat = "0.00"
End With
```